# How to delay an event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery can you do something after you press a button and the timer starts to go from 3 seconds down to 0?

Like you have a button. You press it. 3 Seconds go by and bam.. an event fires.

Answer (score 6):

The `delay()` function ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)) :

> Description: Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

For your example:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("[element]").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .delay() refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)-function.

They have a nice example in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) about this, which fits exactly to your question.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("yourelement").delay(3000).fadeIn(400);
});
```